# Rails: How to not create new join models for newly associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, has-many-through, associated-object

I'm working in Ruby on Rails 4.1.6. I have two associated models (Post and User) through another one (Comment).

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :comments
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => false
  has_many :users, through: :comments
end
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: :comments_count
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I'm creating new Post then new join model Comment with empty content. Is there any way to switch off that automatic creation?

**EDIT:**

I'm populating my database with sample_data.rake file like this:

```
.
.
.
users = neighborhood.users.limit(6)
category = PostCategory.find(1)
50.times do
  title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(1)
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(10)
  users.each { |user| user.posts.create!(title: title, content: content, neighborhood: neighborhood, user: user, post_category: category) }
end
```

And then when I'm creating new Post for User, comment is also created what I don't want.

**EDIT 2:**

In database it looks like this:

```
id  | user_id | post_id | content |         created_at         |         updated_at         
-----+---------+---------+---------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |     100 |       1 |         | 2014-10-30 15:36:52.141408 | 2014-10-30 15:36:52.141408
  2 |      99 |       2 |         | 2014-10-30 15:36:52.173397 | 2014-10-30 15:36:52.173397
.
.
.
297 |      98 |     297 |         | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.184889 | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.184889
298 |      97 |     298 |         | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.215618 | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.215618
299 |      96 |     299 |         | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.237478 | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.237478
300 |      95 |     300 |         | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.258608 | 2014-10-30 15:37:00.258608
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Are you asking whether a user can create a post without there being a comment automatically created?

Comment: Show how you try to create your `Post` record?

Comment: I added it to my question and explained little more.

Comment: @Damian show your `Comment` with empty content.

Comment: Your data model seems flawed. The way it is, a post belongs to a user if he has commented on it once. Therefore, you don't get "user's own posts" but rather "posts that a user is discussing". Therefore, if you create a new such post for the user, it implies that he has discussed it so there should exist a comment that points it out. User's own posts would imply a post having a`user_id` and a direct `belongs_to :user` without `:through`. What functionality are you trying to implement?

Comment: @D-side I'm trying to implement usual post system with comments and likes. Posts have user_id of user, which created it. I wanted also to implement comments, but with easy comments finding for posts and users. So finally should I just create Comment model with post_id and user_id fields in tradicional way?

Comment: Yep, that's right. A `Comment` belongs to a `Post` and to a `User` in different ways (relevance and authorship respectively), that is, associations for these should be independent.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it in normal way. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `has_many :users, through: :comments` association here so you can't create `Post` associated to `User` without creating join model - `Comment`. This is consequence of your data model.

Comment: So could you tell me how can I do it with the same funcionallity?